# How to remove the first 4 characters from a string if it matches a pattern in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
"h3. My Title Goes Here"
```

I basically want to remove the first four characters from the string so that I just get back:

```
"My Title Goes Here".
```

The thing is I am iterating over an array of strings and not all have the `h3.` part in front so I can't just ditch the first four characters blindly.

I checked the docs and the closest thing I could find was `chomp`, but that only works for the end of a string.

Right now I am doing this:

```
"h3. My Title Goes Here".reverse.chomp(" .3h").reverse
```

This gives me my desired output, but there has to be a better way. I don't want to reverse a string twice for no reason. Is there another method that will work?

Comment: +1 Well written question. Would give +2 if I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To alter the original string, use `sub!`, e.g.:

```
my_strings = [ "h3. My Title Goes Here", "No h3. at the start of this line" ]
my_strings.each { |s| s.sub!(/^h3\. /, '') }
```

To not alter the original and only return the result, remove the exclamation point, i.e. use `sub`. In the general case you may have regular expressions that you can and want to match more than one instance of, in that case use `gsub!` and `gsub`—without the `g` only the first match is replaced (as you want here, and in any case the `^` can only match once to the start of the string).

Comment: Good point about the sub vs gsub.  If I understand correctly sub will definitely be better in this case since there is no point checking the whole string.  I only need the first occurrence at the very beginning of the string.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 Good point - I forgot that Ruby has both `sub` and `gsub` and have fixed my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000816) with a regular expression:

```
s = 'h3. foo'
s.sub!(/^h[0-9]+\. /, '')
puts s
```

Output:

```
foo
```

The regular expression should be understood as follows:

```
^     Match from the start of the string.
h     A literal "h".
[0-9] A digit from 0-9.
+     One or more of the previous (i.e. one or more digits)
\.    A literal period.
      A space (yes, spaces are significant by default in regular expressions!)
```

You can modify the regular expression to suit your needs. See a regular expression tutorial or syntax guide, for example [here](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#11).

Answer (score 2):

A standard approach would be to use [regular expressions](http://www.stedee.id.au/So_You_Want_to_Learn_Regular_Expressions):

```
"h3. My Title Goes Here".gsub /^h3\. /, '' #=> "My Title Goes Here"
```

[`gsub`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub) means globally substitute and it replaces a pattern by a string, in this case an empty string.

The regular expression is enclosed in `/` and constitutes of:

`^` means beginning of the string
`h3` is matched literally, so it means `h3`
`\.` - a dot normally means any character so we escape it with a backslash
 is matched literally